# Do you adjust p values at each test or after all tests completed?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, p-value, multiple-comparisons, generalized-additive-model

Using several separate generalized additive models, do I adjust p-values after each one, or after all models?

```
mgcv::gam(ROI1 ~ s(Age) + Gender, method = "REML", data = DF)
mgcv::gam(ROI2 ~ s(Age) + Gender, method = "REML", data = DF)
mgcv::gam(ROI3 ~ s(Age) + Gender, method = "REML", data = DF)

mgcv::gam(ROI1 ~ s(test_score, by = Age_group) + Age_group + Gender, method = "REML", data = DF) # 4 different age groups
mgcv::gam(ROI2 ~ s(test_score, by = Age_group) + Age_group + Gender, method = "REML", data = DF) # 4 different age groups
mgcv::gam(ROI3 ~ s(test_score, by = Age_group) + Age_group + Gender, method = "REML", data = DF) # 4 different age groups
```

This provides a total of 6 models with 18 p-values.

My questions are:

1. In the relevant literature to my study, only one paper mentions using FDR p value adjustment, the majority seem to report unadjusted p-values. I am unsure if I need to correct p values at all?
2. If FDR adjustment is needed, should I use `p.adjust` once with 18 p-values, or after each model, individually?